# Determine the value of the function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\leq1$ at every $x\in(0,1)$. If $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, show that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Show that $g(x)=x-f(x)$ is increasing and note $g(0)=g(1)=0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x):=x-f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1].$ In particular, note that it is differentiable in $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$. What can you say about $g'(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$? Noting that $g(0)=g(1)=0,$ what can you then conclude?